# I don't understand the use of "while(true)" and "for(; ;)" loops in C#!

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

sample code for **While(true)** loop  :

```
    public void HandleConnection()
    {
        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
        while (true)   /**Don't understand this while(true) loop**/
        {
            buffer = new byte[1024];
            n = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (n == 0)
            {
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Sample code for **for(; ;)** loop:

```
     public void readLine(NetworkStream inputStream)
     {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {

            char[] buffer = new char[128];
            int n;

            for (; ; ) /**Don't understand this for(; ;) loop**/
            {
                n = reader.Read();
                if (n == -1 || n == '\n')
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
      }
```

Can anybody give a clear understanding of the above loop statements with reffering to the sample code provided? Thank you for your help!

Comment: They are like any other loop: they will execute as long as the condition is true (which will always be in these "special cases") or until exited with `break`, `return`, `goto` or `throw` (am I missing any method?).

Answer (score 5):

The first one should be easy:

```
while(true)
```

This just means that you should loop infinitely (unless there is some `break` inside the loop). It's meaning should be clear if you would just read it as a regular English line of text.

The other is a bit more tricky to explain:

```
for( ; ; )
```

Usually the part inside `( ... )` contains three statements: (1) a starting point, (2) an exit condition, (3) an increment. Without these three statements, it will just loop infinitely. Mainly because there is no exit-condition.

Comment: Actually, you can have #1 (`initializers`) and #3 (`iterators`) and still not have #2 (`expression`) with `for`. A missing `expression` is simply taken as "true": that is, `for(x;;y)` is equivalent of `for(x;true;y)`.

Comment: That's true, but lets not make it too complicated right away.

Answer (score 4):

Those are infinite loops. In the first case you are looping indefinitely to read from a network stream, and in the second case you are reading from a file stream.

In both cases, you can use `break` when some condition is satisfied to break the loop.

Comment: How can a loop that has a well-defined exit condition be infinite? :(

Comment: Infinite loops are usually something people want to avoid unless it is part of the design. In the majority of the cases, you use an infinite loop when you need to iterate over something for an indefinite amount of time, such as when reading from sockets, or when waiting for a specific input from the keyboard, that is, keep doing something until something else which is usually outside the control of your program happens.

Answer (score 4):

The most idiomatic way to implement such a loop is IMO a do-while loop. This way, you don't need the somewhat confusing infinite loop with break statement.

For instance, your first example could become:

```
int n;
do 
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    n = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
} while (n != 0);
```

The do-while loop always executes the loop body once, and tests the while condition after each iteration.

Comment: What i must use: `do {read} while(stream.DataAvailable)` or `while(stream.DataAvailable) {read}` ?

Answer (score 3):

There are both loops which will never terminate. `while(true)` simply because `true` will always be true, the latter because there's no termination condition specified.

They are simply being used to execute code repeatedly until the loop is broken elsewhere, i.e. when `n` is equal to zero for the former, and when `n` is equal to -1 or '
\n' (new line character) in the latter.

The first could be rewritten as:

```
    n = 1;

    while (n)
    {
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        n = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Both of these syntax are way to implement **infinite loops**.

**While** loop says read until there is nothing to read in stream.

**For** loop say read until you get a newline char or -1.

Comment: But in the examples they are no more infinite than: `n = f(); while (!n) { n = f(); }`, so something else must be at work ;-)

Answer (score 2):

In both case, you could switch the while and the for. Both will loop forever if you don't put a break inside. I prefer the while(true) with a break than the for.

Answer (score 1):

Code explanation:

```
public void HandleConnection()
{
    int n;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
    NetworkStream networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
    networkStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    while (true)   // This is a infinity loop and does never stop ( same in the for (;;) loop )
    {
        buffer = new byte[1024];
        n = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        // Check if there has been data on the network stream
        if (n == 0)
        {
            // No data has been read, exit from the infinity loop
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# has two basic loop constructs.  The *while* and *for* statement lets you check the loop exit condition at the beginning of the loop.  The *do-while* statement lets you check the loop exit condition at the end of the loop.

But what do you do when you want to check the loop exit condition in the *middle*?

You simply use one of those statements and *not* check the loop exit condition in them:

```
for (;;) {
    statements;
    if (exitExpression) break;
    statements;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While(true) is infinite loop. Loop will run until `networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` returns 0. If 0 value will be return then loop will break:

```
  if (n == 0)
  {
    break;
  }
```

Same goes for 'for' loop. Loop will again run infinitely. Application will go out of the loop when  `reader.Read();` return value **-1** or **'\n'**. Important thing to remember is that when you use double logic **OR** operator  (n == -1 || n == '\n') instead of single one (n == -1 | n == '\n'), is enough to enter 'if' statement when first logic statement is true.  If the first logic statement is true, the second won't be even checked.

Comment: Why is it an infinite loop here? `while (true) {}` is "infinite", but this has a clear break-condition.

Comment: The loop verification statement is the example is always true that's why THE loop can work infinitely. The fact it can work infinitely does not not mean it have to or always should.

Comment: But this can also work infinitely: `n = false; while(n) { if (nevertrue) { n = true } }` ...